# Stuck keyed drill chuck

Tags: tools, screws, drill

I have an older Black and Decker KR650RE reversible hammer drill. I need to replace the chuck however the screw on the inside seems damaged. How can I remove the chuck.
Any help much appreciated. Thanks! [image: inside drill chuck]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gently tap an old screwdriver in there and consider it may be a left-hand thread.

Worked for me in the past.

That damage is due to drill bits spinning in the past when not the chuck was not sufficiently tightened.

Comment: also double-ended drill bits. can make a mess in there if they slip.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and a friend suggested holding a screwdriver on the screw and tapping it with a hammer. It took a few attempts but eventually it loosened enough I was able to unscrew it (with left-hand thread).